# How does URL without extensions such as HTML work?

Tags: html, url, uri

For example,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

ask does not have .html but takes me to the page I want. How does this all work? And where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is made from the `.htaccess` file where you make rules for your website/server. 
By having `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` as the address the server will interpret it as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.php` or `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.html`...

You can check [this site](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file in your root folder of your domain with following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```